# Connection error on GRPC devcontainers ran manually vs ran with VSCode

Tags: docker, grpc, vscode-devcontainer, devcontainer

### Context

I work on a project split up in two, each subproject consist of a GRPC client/server and the two are meant to talk to each other from their own containers.

I have been running the project(s) with VS Code devcontainer extension succesfully and now I want to be able to reproduce that setup without VSCode, I need to be able to get an interactive terminal in the two containers.

I came accross [this python script](https://github.com/jkitchin/devcontainer) which seems like a good place to start as it parses the most common devcontainer options and does the build and run. With it I can run the two container successfully, however I am getting into connection issues.

### Situation

1. Client C sends a `ping` message to server S on port 55055 - server S receives the ping and send a pong to C on the same communication channel - C receives the pong.
2. Server S sends a notification to C on port 55056 - and that seems to fail.

Here is the error message from grpc:

```
rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection closed before server preface received
```

Note: it will be very hard to reproduce a minimal example in this context - I am happy to add any precision if necessary

**EDIT:** My docker-compose attempt:

```
ervices:
  prime:
    image: "my/prime:development"
    container_name: "my-prime"
    build:
      context: ${PRIME_PATH}
      dockerfile: .devcontainer/Dockerfile
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    command: bash
    ports:
      - 55055:55055
    volumes:
      - prime:/prime
      - type: bind
        source: ${PRIME_PATH}
        target: /prime
    working_dir: /prime    
  plugin:
    image: "my/tfplugin:development"
    container_name: "tfplugin"
    build:
      context: ${PLUGIN_PATH}
      dockerfile: .devcontainer/Dockerfile
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    ports:
      - 55056:55056
    volumes:
      - plugin:/home/tfprime/.cache/bazel
      - type: bind
        source: ${PLUGIN_PATH}
        target: /tfprime
    working_dir: /tfprime     

volumes:
  prime:
  plugin:
```

Comment: Without more info it's difficult to answer; one thought is that you may be mapping port `55056` to a [TLS server and connecting without TLS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71627962/11810946). At a minimum please provide info on the apps (you don't mention a language) and ideally some logs.

Comment: This is described as a grpc problem, but from the detail you provided it's probably a docker networking problem. This question isn't answerable as written, you need to include at least how you're deploying your containers at a very minimum.

Comment: I've added my docker-compose attempt as  it gives me the same error