# Unable to reach service running in Cloud Run

Tags: google-cloud-platform, port, google-cloud-run

I'm using a workflow to push my image in the Artifact Registry.

I deploy a service from that image.

The service is running. The port defined in GCP is getting picked up in the environment.

As per the log, my service is running and listening on that port.

[image]
[image]
[image]

I am unable to reach my container on that port. Port checker tool report this port as closed. Making call from my local machine to the endpoint times out.

What am I missing here?

Deploying the test container hello is working and I'm able to reach the port 8080. But no other ports are working.

## Update

This is how I start the service with Go:

```
    port := os.Getenv("PORT")

    fmt.Println("PORT:" + port)

    listener, err := net.Listen("tcp", fmt.Sprintf("0.0.0.0:%s", port))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error on listen")
        panic(err)
    }

    srv := grpc.NewServer()
    pb.RegisterWallApiServer(srv, &server{})
    reflection.Register(srv)

    fmt.Println("Starting server on port " + port)
    if err = srv.Serve(listener); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error on serve")
        panic(err)
    }
```

After using the default port 8080, Exposing it in the image, and sent my request to port 443. I'm getting this error;

rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection closed before server preface received.

This is how I make the call

```
    func main() {
    creds := insecure.NewCredentials()
    address := "idfi-api-w2b5dfqtlq-uc.a.run.app:443"
    conn, err := grpc.Dial(address, grpc.WithTransportCredentials(creds))

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to connect: %v", err)
    }
    defer conn.Close()

    client := pb.NewWallApiClient(conn)
    res, err := client.SetWallSignature(context.Background(), &pb.WallSignatureRequest{Address: "0x"})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to post message: %v", err)
    }
    log.Println(res.Success)
}
```

Comment: Are your container listening for requests on `0.0.0.0`? As you can read in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/container-contract), it is necessary in addition to listening on the configured `PORT`.  To confirm that point, please, try running your container in the default `8080` port and see if it works properly.

Comment: Per the comment above, you need to listen on `0.0.0.0` and use port `8080` by default.  If you want to listen on a custom port, you'll need to specify that (https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/containers#configure-port).

Comment: Can you please add how are you making the request to the CR service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GCP documentation, when describing how to [listen on requests in the correct port](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/container-contract#port), states:

> For Cloud Run services, the container must listen for requests on `0.0.0.0`
> on the port to which requests are sent. By default, requests are sent to
> `8080`, but you can [configure Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/containers#configure-port) to send requests to the port of
> your choice. Cloud Run injects the `PORT` environment variable into the
> container. Inside Cloud Run container instances, the value of the `PORT`
> environment variable always reflects the port to which requests are sent.
> It defaults to `8080`.

According to your screenshot it seems you already [configured](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/containers#configure-port) a different port for your application.

If your application is starting successfully then, as indicated in my comment, the error could be related to the fact that your application is not listening in all the network interfaces, is not listening for requests on `0.0.0.0`. To confirm that point, please, try running your container in the default `8080` port and see if it works properly.

If it doesn't, please, try configuring your application to listen for requests on `0.0.0.0`.

The way in which you should configure the application to listen for requests on `0.0.0.0` depends on the actual underlying language/technology you are using (Python, NodeJS, etc): I will be glad to expand the answer to provide you guidance about this point if you include further information about what technology you are using in the question.

As an **update**, sorry, because I missed an important detail that you mention in your question: of course, the configured port is not directly available, you should use port 443 to access your application; Cloud Run will provide the [necessary infrastructure](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/overview/what-is-cloud-run#services) to access your service through an HTTPS endpoint, it acts as a "proxy", placed in front of your application, and that "proxy" redirects the traffic to the configured `PORT`.

Thank you for your new **update**. As indicated in my answer comments, I think the new connectivity issue has to do with the way your client is interacting with your server, probably because you are establishing an insecure connection:

```golang
creds := insecure.NewCredentials()
address := "idfi-api-w2b5dfqtlq-uc.a.run.app:443"
conn, err := grpc.Dial(address, grpc.WithTransportCredentials(creds))
```

I am not still very fluent with go, but as I tried explaining in the comments as well, please, consider review [this post](https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Serverless/Unable-to-connect-to-Cloud-Run-gRPC-server/m-p/422280/highlight/true#M345) and the answer provided by Dustin Decker. He mentions:

> I encountered this while testing with:
>
> `grpc.WithTransportCredentials(grpc.WithInsecure())`
> This does not work because it causes gRPC to make the request using
> H2C (HTTP/2 without TLS), which fails at the Cloud Run ingress with
> a 503, never reaching the application.

It means that you need to provide an appropriate certificate trust configuration for your client.

For instance, the mentioned post propose the following solution:

> Make sure you're running Cloud Run with HTTP/2 end to end if you
> require gRPC streaming (and better performance in general), and
> make sure you're providing some certificates. Either pinned or
> importing your CA store. Example:
>
> ```golang
>   systemRoots, err := x509.SystemCertPool()
>   if err != nil {
>       panic(errors.Wrap(err, "cannot load root CA certs"))
>   }
>   creds := credentials.NewTLS(&tls.Config{
>       RootCAs: systemRoots,
>   })
>
>   conn, err := grpc.DialContext(ctx, addr,
>       grpc.WithTransportCredentials(creds),
>   )
>   if err != nil {
>       panic(err)
>   }
> ```

Comment: Thank You! I have update my question. Still not able to reach my service.

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback @MadeInDreams. I am happy to hear that you were able to do some progress. Regarding the current issue, I think it can be motivated by different reason, usually related to the way your client connects to the server. Please, consider read [this GCP community post](https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Serverless/Unable-to-connect-to-Cloud-Run-gRPC-server/m-p/405509#M271), especially the post from Dustin Decker. [This related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71627962/grpc-error-how-to-solve-connection-closed-before-server-preface-received)

Comment: could be of help as well.

Comment: Thank you so much! In the end the certificate was the issue!

Comment: You are welcome!! I am very happy to see that you managed to solve the problem.