# Cloud Run Service Service-to-Service via gRPC error: "failed to connect to all addresses; no route to path"

Tags: networking, grpc, google-cloud-run, grpc-python

I have two Cloud Run services running, which I will call "backend" and "helper". The backend service is a publicly accessible HTTPS connection, running a Python server. It sends requests to the helper service, which is running a Python gRPC insecure server

```py
...
server = grpc.aio.server(ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10))
server.add_insecure_port('[::]:50051')
...
```

via a Python gRPC client.

```py
...
with open('/.cert.pem', 'rb') as f:
    creds = grpc.ssl_channel_credentials(f.read())
client_channel = grpc.aio.secure_channel(
    hostname,
    creds,
)
...
```

where `hostname` is the hostname of the embedding service as it is displayed on cloud run, i.e. https://:. I've also tried two different certificates for the cert.pem file (just in case I configured something incorrectly on the infrastucture). The first attempt was one of the certificates listed [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/main/endpoints/roots.pem), and the second attempt I used [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/certificate-authority-service/docs/requesting-certificates) to setup a certificate pool with google and request a certificate, then pass that to my cloud run service via a mounted secret. Neither of these approaches alleviated the problem.

To simplify the issue, the helper service is just running the [standard health check protocol](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/src/proto/grpc/health/v1/health.proto).

To help isolate the problem, I have controlled for the following things:

- both backend and helper have role: "roles/run.invoker" and member "allUsers"
- both services allow INGRESS_TRAFFIC_ALL.
- the helper service has end-to-end HTTP/2 enabled.
- I've confirmed that the helper service is publicly accessible. Running the client code from my local device against the cloud-run service successfully returns a request.

Finally, the specific error I am receiving is (using a random IPv6 address)

```
>>> AioRpcError of RPC that terminated with: status = StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE details = "failed to connect to all addresses; last error: UNKNOWN: ipv6:%5B1234:1234:1234:12::12%5D:443: No route to host"
```

I suspect this is a network problem as it takes roughly 80 seconds of hanging before this error appears.

Comment: Hi, can you check this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76120493/unable-to-reach-service-running-in-cloud-run).Also check the certificate and port once.Have a look at this [post](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/28323)

Comment: I've reviewed both of the sources, and from what I understand they both indicate the issue is not passing proper tls credentials to the gRPC client. I tried to implement both of the suggestions (1) I copied the first certificate [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/main/endpoints/roots.pem) and fed it as bytes directly to my ssl_channel initializer `grpc.ssl_channel_credentials(cert_bytes)` (2) I created a certificate with GCP following [these steps](https://cloud.google.com/certificate-authority-service/docs/requesting-certificates), and used that.

Comment: Neither of them made any difference. It's still the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to this:

```
https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/issues#ipv6-and-vpc-egress
```

The direct VPC access preview is not currently compatible with IPv6. After changing my subnet to IPv4 only and routing all requests through VPC (not just ones to private IDs, not sure why this was needed though), I was able to get things working.

This also assumes that you pass valid ssl/tls credentials on the client side.